# How can I solve an incompatible types error when trying to develop a dynamic filter query for D365-specific data types in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: odata, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365-operations

I am currently trying to use Azure Logic Apps to List Items Present in a Table in Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations using a dynamic filterQuery detemined by input at runtime as shown below:
[D365 F&O connector for List Items present in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XEZ9.png)

However, for some of the filter queries, we encounter errors where the data type in D365 is different from the one in Logic Apps, resulting in incompatible type error as shown below:
[Error message received from logic app - A binary operator with incompatible types was detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUxGg.png)

For reference, to meet the dynamic filtering requirement, what I am doing is appending continuously all required filters to a string in such a manner using a loop, extracting key-value pairs from a JSON payload determined at runtime:
[Append to filter query: and  eq ''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvMd.png)

The fields throwing errors have data types in D365 "enum" and "bool" respectively.
Bool data types have the error: "A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.NoYes' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'".
Enum data types have the error: "A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'", where  is the name of the key I wish to filter for.

Is there a simple way to resolve this error? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ask has been addressed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/314559/azure-logic-apps-to-d365-fampo-flow-results-in-dif.html

However, in this kind of scenario I would suggest to :

1. First run the Flow with Dynamics action without the filter.
2. Second check the results of the Flow run, and look for the value you want to put the filtering on.
3. Third copy the field name (without quotes) and use that property name ( with the conditions) in the filter.